# How come the output will be '100' and '500'?

Tags: java

I am confused why the output of the below program prints 100 and 500?
Can anybody explain how this happens?

```
public class ArraysInJava
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[3]; 
        a[1] = 50; 
        Object o = a; 
        int[] b = (int[])o; 
        b[1] = 100; 
        System.out.println(a[1]); 
        ((int[])o)[1] = 500; 
        System.out.println(a[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect it to print? Why?

Comment: why wouldn't it be 100 and 500?

Comment: @S.K. Because you've assigned `500` to the first element of the array - at no point have you actually changed the memory reference used by any of the objects, you've just made them point to each other

Comment: Because you have created only one object of Integer Array and you are changing the value of `index 1` in mentioned steps. So, Even if you typecast the `int[] to object` and `object to int[]` the reference of created object will remain the same. Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do this line by line...

```
public class ArraysInJava
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[3]; // a = {0, 0, 0} as default value for int elements is 0
        a[1] = 50; // a = {0, 50, 0}
        Object o = a; // o = a = {0, 50, 0} - casting affects the variable type, the referenced object remains the same (recall that objects are saved by reference)
        int[] b = (int[])o; // b = o = a = {0, 50, 0}
        b[1] = 100; // b = o = a = {0, 100, 0}
        System.out.println(a[1]); // Prints 100
        ((int[])o)[1] = 500; // b = o = a = {0, 500, 0}
        System.out.println(a[1]); // Prints 500
    }
}
```

All the casting doesn't do anything because it only affects what you can do on it at compile-time. For example, you can't write `o[1]` because it is not an array at compile time.

### Edit

[Carlos Heuberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85421/carlos-heuberger) did bring up an important point in the comments. I think the missing part is about data types.

There are two main data types: primitive data types and non-primitive data types.

Primitive data types consist of `byte`, `short`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `char`, `boolean`. When you pass variables of these data types into methods, or assign to another variable, you are passing in the *value*.

```
int a = 15;
int b = a; // b now holds 15
```

Non-primitive data types (you can call them object types) are all other types outside of all mentioned above. This includes arrays (also arrays of primitive types), enums, classes, interfaces and `String`.

When you pass variables of these data types into methods, or assign them to another variable, you are passing in the *reference* of the object.

```
int[] a = {1, 2};
Object b = a; // "b" now holds the reference (memory address) of the "a"
int[] c = b; // "c" now also points to the exact same array
b = null; // "b" holds no memory reference now, "a" and "c" continues to hold reference of the same array
```

Comment: the important point is not the casting, but that `=` does not copy the array, which is an object, (unlike what happens with primitives)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yup, when I read again I think the important point is indeed about knowing objects are reference type.

Comment: @Sreejith G This is the practical presentation which will elaborate my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you debug the code you can find following actions:

1. first of all a = [0,0,0]
2. a = [0,50,0]
3. o = [0,50,0]
4. b = [0,50,0]
5. b = [0,100,0] -> o = [0,100,0] -> a = [0,100,0]
6. printed a[1] = 100
7. o[1] = 500 -> o = [0,500,0] -> b = [0,500,0] -> a = [0,500,0]
8. printed a[1] = 500

This is how values are changed for a[1].

**Basically there is the same array a which is getting changed all the way.**

Comment: kind of confusing, does not explain why the values of `b` *go to* `o` and than to `c`.  Main point is that they are all the same object (`b === o === a` or so)

Comment: Yes because they are all same, i didnt mention that

Answer (score 1):

Draw memory  models and track each reference, see mine in comments in the code if you understand this it will clear your confusion.   `a, b, and o` are the references

```
a[1]------> 50
a[1]------> 50 <------------o[1]
a[1], b[1]------->50 <---------------o[1]
a[1], b[1] -------->100 <-----------o[1]  (but the value 50 is overwritten with 100)
a[1], b[1] -------->500<-----------o[1]  (but the value 100 is overwritten with 500)
```

```
int[] a = new int[3]; 
            a[1] = 50;  // a------> 50,
            Object o = a;  //  a------> 50 <------------o
            int[] b = (int[])o; // a, b------->50 <---------------o
            b[1] = 100;          //a, b -------->100 <-----------o(but the value 50 is overwritten with 100)
            System.out.println(a[1]);  // so prints 100
            ((int[])o)[1] = 500; //a, b -------->500<-----------o(but the value 100 is overwritten with 500)
            System.out.println(a[1]); // hence prints 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually referencing the same memory address(pointers), hence when you change the value the content in the memory address change too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your variables `o`, `b`, `a` are all references to the same array.
So whichever of these references you use to modify the second element of the array, the array's first element will change.

First you change it to 50 using `a[1]=50`
Then you change it to 100 using `b[1]=100`
Then you change it to 500 using `(int[] o)[1]=500`

Comment: this is also valid for the second element of the array, which is actually being changed...

Comment: Oh oops, that's what I meant. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here, you created an array object `a` and at position 1 you are initializing by 50. 
`Object o` is reference variable of `a`, it means both are holding save value and location. After that you created another reference variable `b` of `o`, here `b` is reference variable of `o` and `o` is reference variable of `a` so that b is also a reference variable `a`.
If try to update value by any reference variable, the all references will hold same value (means, value of all reference will be change). In this example you doing same thing.

Value of `a` at 1 updated by reference variable `b`, --> line 9

Value of `a` at 1 updated by reference variable `o`, --> line 11

Answer (score 0):

Array is an Object in java. And when you use '=' assignment operator with objects it actually points to same object in memory, It does not create new one. like

```
int[] a = new int[3]; 
a[1] = 50; 
Object o = a;   // now o and a will point to same object in memory
                //Any changes done in either a or o will reflect in both

int[] b = (int[])o;   // now a,b and o pointing to same array in memory
b[1] = 100;            
System.out.println(a[1]); 
((int[])o)[1] = 500; 
System.out.println(a[1]);
```

So There is only one array in memory; a,b and o pointing to same array, so any changes made to array by using any of refernce variable a,b or o will done same array.